# How to read latitude and longitude information from /GPSFix message in my bagfile?

Tags: ros, gps, bagfiles, gpsd-client

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi friends,
i am having a bagfile containing /GPSFix information. i want to read and publish its information using gpsd. for that i used [gpsd_client](http://www.ros.org/wiki/gpsd_client/Tutorials/Getting%20Started%20with%20gpsd_client) tutorial.

I have given rosbag node port number for gpsd_client otherwise it is showing error. When i run gpsd_client it says "GPSD opened" but my gpsd_subscriber is not printing latitude and longitude information.

Please help me to solve this problem.

This is my gpsd_client

```
mit@mit-HP-Pro-3330-SFF:~/Desktop/Bagfiles$ rostopic info /GPSFix 
Type: gps_common/GPSFix

Publishers: None

Subscribers: 
 * /gps_subscriber (http://mit-HP-Pro-3330-SFF:33912/)


mit@mit-HP-Pro-3330-SFF:~/Desktop/Bagfiles$ rosrun gpsd_client gpsd_client _host:=localhost _port:=33912
[ INFO] [1374726241.992697318]: GPSd opened
```

This is my gpsd_subscriber

```
 mit@mit-HP-Pro-3330-SFF:~/Desktop/gps_test$ rosrun gpsd_subscriber gpsTest
```

This is my gpsd_subscriber source code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/NavSatFix.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/NavSatStatus.h>


using namespace sensor_msgs;

void callback(const NavSatFixConstPtr &fix) {

  if (fix->status.status == NavSatStatus::STATUS_NO_FIX) {
    std::cout << "Unable to get a fix on the location." << std::endl;
    return;
  }

  std::cout << "Current Latitude: " << fix->latitude << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Current Longitude " << fix->longitude << std::endl;

}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  ros::init(argc, argv, "gps_subscriber");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;

  ros::Subscriber gps_sub = nh.subscribe("/GPSFix", 1, callback);

  ros::spin();
  return 0;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/68812/how-to-read-latitude-and-longitude-information-from-/gpsfix-message-in-my-bagfile?/) by [Bindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/5524/bindu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2013-07-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am afraid the thing you trying to accomplish is not implemented.

`gpsd_client` can only **receive** data from `gpsd` daemon and cannot send data back to it.

The typical scheme to work with `GPSd` is as follows:

`GPS device -> GPSd -> gpsd_client -> ROS message callback`

The one you have explained is:

`rosbag -> /dev/null`

`GPSd -> gpsd_client -> ROS message callback`

Thus you have two parallel data streams not connected to each other, even more, `GPSd` has no source of data at all and that is why you receive nothing in callback.

All you have to do is simply subscribe to a topic broadcasted by `rosbag` without all these `GPSd` and `gpsd_client`.

**EDIT:**

Additionally, if you ran `rosbag` together with `gpsd_client` they may interfere while publishing to the same topic.

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2013-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/5524/bindu/) on 2013-07-24**:
thank you Boris. . .

**Comment by [Bindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/5524/bindu/) on 2013-07-31**:
i need to import this latitude and longitude information to my c++ program . how can i do that? please help

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2013-07-31**:
You have to use ros::Subscriber and subscribe to your GPS topic. Please go through [beginner tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials) to see how to write subscriber in C++.

**Comment by [weiy1991](https://answers.ros.org/users/23665/weiy1991/) on 2015-09-07**:
Dose anyone know how to get the track message from gpsd_client?